# Como abrir o WebView na última URL acessada

Tags: java, android, webview

Estou fazendo um app web com login apenas de um nick.

Toda vez que a pessoa abre o app, ele entra apenas na variável `url` onde a página pede o nickname, mas eu queria que ele salvasse a última URL para acessar ela na próxima vez que o usuário abrir o app, e se não tiver nenhuma URL salva, ele abra a URL padrão. Pois assim o usuário não precisar digitar o seu nick toda vez.

Esse é o meu código atual:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //Escconde TopBar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declanação variavel url
        String url = "http://endereçodomeusiteapp";
        String eror = "Sem erro";


       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //Habilita javaScript
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Url Padrão.
        webView.loadUrl(url);


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int eror, String description, String html) {
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/conex.html");

        }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, Leônidas!

Como você diz que o login é apenas um nick, vou considerar que o nível de segurança não deva ser um problema. Desse jeito, podemos resolver seu problema da seguinte forma

1 - Crie um método para salvar sua última `url`

```
public void salvaUrl(String url, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
   editor.putInt(EXTRAS_ULTIMA_URL, url);
   editor.apply();
}
```

2 - Crie outro método para recuperar

```
public String recuperaUrl(String nomePref, SharedPreferences prefs) {
   // Esse null é um valor padrão caso não exista valor (url) salvo
   return prefs.getString(nomePref, null);
}
```

3 - No método `onStop` da `Activity` salve a última url usando o método do passo 2

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
   super.onStop();
   if (webView != null && mPrefs != null) {
      salvaUrl(webView.getUrl(), mEditor);
   }
}
```

4 - Agora vamos juntar tudo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static String EXTRAS_ULTIMA_URL = "extras_ultima_url"; 
    private final static String NOME_PREFS        = "nome_prefs";

    private WebView webView;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //Escconde TopBar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPrefs  = getSharedPreferences(NOME_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEditor = prefs.edit();

        //Declanação variavel url
        String url = "http://endereçodomeusiteapp";
        String eror = "Sem erro";


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        //Habilita javaScript
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Antes de chamar sua url de login, verifique se há uma última 
        // url salva utilizando o método criado no passo 1
        String ultimaUrl = recuperaUrl(EXTRAS_ULTIMA_URL, mPrefs);

        if (ultimaUtl != null) {
           webView.loadUrl(utlimaUrl);
        }
        else {
           webView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int eror, String description, String html) {
                    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/conex.html");

        }});
     }

     public void salvaUrl(String url, SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
          editor.putInt(EXTRAS_ULTIMA_URL, url);
          editor.apply();
     }

     public String recuperaUrl(String nomePref, SharedPreferences prefs) {
         // Esse null é um valor padrão caso não exista valor (url) salvo
         return prefs.getString(nomePref, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (webView != null && mPrefs != null) {
            salvaUrl(webView.getUrl(), mEditor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, Deus lhe abençoe. Funcionou perfeitamente, sou muito grato pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Fico muito agradecido em ver que consegui lhe ajudar. Abraço!